# How to attach image email on laravel 5.3 using Mail Facade?

Tags: laravel

I got image on mail template but when i send it does not carry the image. what should i do.

**Template HTML**

```
<img src="/img/blahblah.jpg"> //this image does not display on receiver of mail
```

**App\Mail\Subscribe**

```
public function build() {
  return $this->view('mail.subscribe');
}
```

Comment: Try fully qualified URL e.g. ```http://yourdomain.com/img/blahblah.jpg``` in image ```src```.

Comment: yes i think about this idea but is there an easy way rather making new routing for this?

Comment: Please check Alexey's answer. But it may increase the size of your email.

Comment: is there another solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> To embed an inline image, use the embed method on the $message variable within your email template. Laravel automatically makes the $message variable available to all of your email templates, so you don't need to worry about passing it in manually

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToFile) }}">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#inline-attachments

Comment: how did you set this $message?

Comment: Thanks this solve my problem. Hint: first make a route that display the image like domain.com/template/image/{image} and answer on the above change the path to file using the routing name to display the image. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

In your mail template use the `asset` helper function to get the full url of the image as:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/blahblah.jpg') }}">
```

From docs

> Generate a URL for an `asset` using the current scheme of the request
>   (HTTP or HTTPS)

Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset).

Comment: i use this method but not working i think i need to pull the image from new route

Comment: I hope your image is in `public` folder.

Comment: yes. it is in public/img/subscribe.png i have route master.dev/template/email. and the image display well. the problem is just when i used this template it does not display on receiver of the mail

Comment: Are you sending e-mails using queues?

Comment: Check in the dev console of the browser on receiver's mail that what is URL of the image generated?